# How can I set the CssClass property of THEAD in a dynamically created Html Table

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I am using Bootstrap 4 which allows me to have a special style for the table header if I use it like this:

```
<table class='table table-bordered'>
    <thead class='thead-dark'>
       <!-- etc -->
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <!-- etc -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In my code, I am dynamically creating `Table` object and appending it to the form.

```
Table tbl = new Table;
tbl.cssClass = "table table-bordered";
TableRow tr = new TableRow();
tr.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;   //this will put the row in the header
   // but I need to set the class of the <thead> element


TableCell td = new TableCell();

td.Text = "Testing 123";
tr.Cells.Add(td);
tbl.Rows.Add(tr);


tbl.header.cssClass = "thead-dark";   // Not valid, but something like this

this.Controls.Add(tbl);
```

How can I assign the className `thead-dark` to the table head section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this dynamically through the code behind, but you could dynamically set the class on the  using javascript.

```
// Get the table by id
var table = document.getElementById("tableId");
// Get the thead element assuming it is the direct child of your table
// Set the class
table.children[0].className = "thead-dark";
```

Comment: I am aware that it is possible by Javascript, however, I need to perform that on the code-behind level